# How to add the image in top of bar in bar chart?

Tags: android, achartengine

Am using Achartengine library to draw the bar chart.I want add the image in top of the bar.Please refer my below image.I don't know to get the chart like that way.Can any know help me to solve this issue.

[image: Expected Chart Result]

**Bar chart Java Coding**

```
public class Bar_chart {
public Intent getIntent(Context context) {

    double [] test1 = {50,10,20,60};
    String [] test2 = {"1","2","3","4"};


    CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Bar1");
    for (int i = 0; i < test1.length; i++) {

        series.add("Bar" + (i + 1),test1[i]);

    }

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataSet = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset(); 
    dataSet.addSeries(series.toXYSeries()); 

    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer(); 
    renderer.setColor(Color.RED);
    renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 5.5d);
    renderer.setLineWidth((float) 10.5d);

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(); 
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Score");
    mRenderer.setXTitle("Over");

    mRenderer.setShowLegend(true);
    mRenderer.setShowGridX(true); 
    mRenderer.setShowGridY(true);

    mRenderer.setBarSpacing(.5); 
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);

    mRenderer.setXAxisMax(5);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, true);

    for (int j = 0; j < test2.length; j++) {

        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(j+1,test2[j]);

    }

    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, dataSet,mRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);

    return intent;
}
}
```

Comment: Not possible unless u change the source code of library .

Comment: okay.Is it possible to change the source code of library? Did you know an other library to do chart like this way?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to change source code. I don't think any other library that can do this, u have to edit library.

Comment: @keshav Okay.I'll try.